# Provided Host header is not whitelisted on curl call

Tags: json-rpc

I wanted check if I can connect to a remote server to get some information and send a transaction.

First I checked the connection with this :

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_syncing","params":[],"id":1} http://xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx:8545
```

But I've this error :

```
curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 50
curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 50
curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 50
Provided Host header is not whitelisted.
```

What doest it mean? What can I do to resolve it?

Comment: It looks to me like you're missing the closing single quote after the closing bracket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Globbing

Turn [globbing off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26407256/1260906) with `-g` and tell `curl` about the content type being JSON:

```
curl -g -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_syncing","params":[],"id":1}' http://xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx:8545
```

Also there is a `'` missing after the last bracket before the URL parameter.

This is working for me with parity on `localhost`:

```
 0 ✓ user@alcor ~ $ curl -g -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_syncing","params":[],"id":1}' localhost:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"blockGap":null,"currentBlock":"0x2e0567","highestBlock":"0x2df992","startingBlock":"0x2df992","warpChunksAmount":null,"warpChunksProcessed":null},"id":1}
```

---

#### Whitelisting

You need to relaunch the remote host's with a parameter that allows remote connections, e.g. `--jsonrpc-hosts="all"` for parity. For geth, I'm unsure, try `--rpcaddr 0.0.0.0`.

Comment: I tried your solution, I just remplace localhost by my host, but I always have the same error!

Comment: Updated the answer concerning the whitelisting issue.

Comment: Okay I just add `jsonrps-hosts = "all"`and it's working perfectly!! Thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: I've a other question, I've a time out error when I tried to do `sendTransaction`command Have you any idea to resolve this problem?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button, will be hard to nail down your problem in comments here. Also read my post on [Monero meta about follow-up questions](http://meta.monero.stackexchange.com/a/157/100). :-)

Answer (score 1):

Accessing UI remotely has been recently described on Parity Wiki:
https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/UI-Remote-Access

Recommended method is to use SSH and port-forwarding:

```
$ ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 -L 8180:127.0.0.1:8180 -L 8545:127.0.0.1:8545 <user>@<host> -vv
```

it doesn't require any special flags and it provides the best security.