# Publicly hosting parity rpc - Provided Host header is not whitelisted

Tags: json-rpc, parity

I setup an ubuntu test server in the cloud with parity installed. My desire is to publicly expose the parity RPC service on port 8545 for testing purposes. Currently, I am ignoring whether this is [safe](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15361/is-it-safe-to-publicly-host-a-parity-node) or not.

The parity config.toml file is shown below.  When I navigate to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8545 in the browser I see the following message:

> Provided Host header is not whitelisted.

I was expecting instead to see `Used HTTP Method is not allowed. POST or OPTIONS is required`. As a sanity check if I turn parity off I get a page not found error.

config.toml

```
[rpc]
    # Allows Cross-Origin Requests from domain '*'.
    interface = "all"
    cors = "*"
    # Allow connections only using specified addresses.
    hosts = ["", "*"]
```

Related:

- [Curl error](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11491/provided-host-header-is-not-whitelisted-on-curl-call)
- [Is it safe to do this?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15361/is-it-safe-to-publicly-host-a-parity-node)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to run parity with the following option.

> parity --jsonrpc-hosts "all"

This was alluded to [here](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/1812).

Comment: It takes 2 days :)